# how to go one view from another view using with flip animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am flip animation to go from one view to another and animation is working properly but when i am using button action on that view that time application is getting crash.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

my code is:

```
Abtsk1 *secondViewController = [[Abtsk1 alloc] 
                        initWithNibName:@"Abtsk1" 
                        bundle:nil];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown 
                       forView:[[self navigationController] view] cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks
Kunal

Comment: what error that crash produces? could you post the code that crashes actually - this one looks ok for me